# How to dynamically access members of the owner form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class

In a Winforms application, consider the following Form Class:

```
Public Class frmOwner
    Public MyProperty As String = "Test"
    Private Sub btnShowDialog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                    Handles btnShowDialog.Click
        Using frm As New frmDialog
            frm.ShowDialog(Me)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, whenever I want to access `MyProperty` from the dialog form, I use something like this:

```
    MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(Me.Owner, frmOwner).MyProperty)  'Test
```

So far so good. **The problem** comes when I have another form (e.g. `frmOwner2`) that also has the member `MyProperty` and it also shows an instance of `frmDialog`.

**My question** is: how can I determine -from `frmDialog`- which form is the owner to be able to access its *public* members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to reach the owner's certain public properties from the dialog, but the owner might be different classes, then you can choose two different approach: *1., class inheritance 2., implement interface.*

In both cases, You cast to the appropriate parent or interface and then call the property name of that object.

Another way could be using *Reflection*, but in Your case that would be a *cannon against little birds*.

### 1., Class inheritance

You define Your wished public properties in a *parent form*. Then You derive the other forms from this parent using `Inherits ParentForm`directive.

```
Public Class frmOwnerBase

  Protected _MyProperty1 As String
  Public Property MyProperty1() As String
    Get
      Return _MyProperty1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _MyProperty1 = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Protected _MyProperty2 As String
  Public Property MyProperty2() As String
    Get
      Return _MyProperty2
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _MyProperty2 = value
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

Then in the frmOwner1.Designer.vb and frmOwner2.Designer.vb files You re-write the ancestor:

```
Partial Class frmOwner1
  Inherits frmOwnerBase

Partial Class frmOwner2
  Inherits frmOwnerBase
```

### 2., Interface implementation

You define the type and name of the properties in an *interface*. Then in the `frmOwner` and `frmOwner2` classes You apply `Implements InterfaceName` at their declarations. Then You define Your properties with the directive `Public MyProperty As String Implements InterfaceName.MyProperty`

```
Public Interface InterfaceOwner

  Property MyProperty1() As String

  Property MyProperty2() As String

End Interface
```

```vb
Public Class frmOwner
  Implements InterfaceOwner
  Private _MyProperty1 As String
  Public Property MyProperty1() As String Implements InterfaceOwner.MyProperty1
    Get
      Return _MyProperty1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _MyProperty1 = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Private _MyProperty2 As String
  Public Property MyProperty2() As String Implements InterfaceOwner.MyProperty2
    Get
      Return _MyProperty2
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _MyProperty2 = value
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

Comment: +1 for the good suggestion. Using an interface for all the owner forms which share members might be a suitable solution for my situation. I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Well, it's a good idea except that Interfaces cannot have member variables.

Comment: You declare the properties in the interface. The member variables must be declared in the form classes.

Comment: Really thank you for you effort, but what if the owner form member is a control (e.g. BindingSource or even a button) and I want to set some of its properties? I just tried [**this**](http://paste.ofcode.org/aUhy3NTRKxffibMSrvy5Pq), I managed to get the value successfully, but I'm not able to change.

Comment: Wow, I just managed to get this done by implementing the interface + the property in the designer file instead. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: I did work *only* when I implemented the interface and the property inside the form designer file.. thank you again :)

Comment: I'm happy You achieved what You wanted:) But there should not be difference between putting Your code into the code file or into the designer file. Don't forget that the designer file is auto-generated and its content might be overridden by the visual designer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113817/discussion-between-genius-brain-and-attila).